# POST to PHP using AJAX and refresh upon change

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to build a web application that needs to refresh the entire page when there is a change in the database. I would like to achieve this using AJAX and PHP. I would like to POST a single piece of information to the PHP script every 5 seconds and if the returned value from the PHP script is different from a predefined variable, I would like to refresh the entire page.

For example, I have a predefined value in javascript of 200. If the PHP script returns a different value, I would like to refresh the entire page.

I know how to write the PHP, it is just the XJAX I am having issues with. I would also not like to use jquery if possible.

Thanks in advance for any guidance!

EDIT : I would not like to use jquery or any other framework, just raw javascript. I also need to refresh the entire page upon change and run the AJAX every 5 seconds.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: This will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php

Comment: @SandeepBansal Nope, I am asking about POSTing information and refreshing upon change.

Comment: @Himanshugupta I would not like to use jQuery and I would like to refresh upon changes and trigger it to run every 5 seconds.

Comment: The links they provided have how to ajax without jQuery, what else you need?

Comment: There is no way to send something from PHP to the browser, that is, the server can't initiate an ajax call, the browser has to. If you use websockets or server-sent events it's different, but for ajax you have to do long polling, or send an ajax request to the server every 5 seconds to see if anything changed.

Comment: And it's just a basic XMLHttpRequest inside a recursive function with a timeout.

Comment: Maybe he wants to do that from raw javascript, that he means by saying no jquery if possible.., for that this link will surely help http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/ajaxgetpost2.shtml and after that as andeneo said, just make ajax requests every 5 seconds, and if the result is success, just reload the page...

Comment: How do want to keep track of the previous and new DB return value across page refreshes? Will you echo some PHP variable in your client page? If so, please show is what it is.

Comment: @oscargilfc I need to know how to know how to POST information within AJAX and refresh the page upon a change.

Comment: @Drakes I will use PHP to echo the value to compare the AJAX value from when the page loads.

Comment: Then you have to be more specific like: "How can I POST using ajax" or "how do I refresh the entire page?" As some of the answers below says, you only have to use `xhr.open('POST', url, true);`

Comment: @Brandon Perfect. A solution is awaiting you using this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. You can do `if(xmlhttp.responseText !== "<?php echo $currentValue; ?>") {` to check if the PHP-side value has changed. This `watchdog` method is called very 5 seconds through `setInterval`. If there is a change, then the page is refreshed via `document.location.reload(true)` ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)) to prevent reusing the cache.

```
function watchdog() {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5 - whatever, it doesn't hurt
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

      // This is how you can discover a server-side change
      if(xmlhttp.responseText !== "<?php echo $currentValue; ?>") {
        document.location.reload(true); // Don't reuse cache
      }
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("POST","page.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

// Call watchdog() every 5 seconds
setInterval(function(){ watchdog(); }, 5000);
```

**Note:** I chose `setInterval` over `setTimeout` because if the connection to the server fails (500-error, timeout, etc.), then the response logic may otherwise fail to trigger another `setTimeout`. `setInterval` ensures the server is polled consistently regardless of connection failures.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. Thanks very much, I am sure this code will help lots of people!

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX can be executed every 5 seconds using the setInterval() function.
And you can call to refresh the page from AJAX request completion callback.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. I have used javascript setInterval function which will make ajax call every 5 seconds. Now please make efforts to make changes in code as per your requirements and take it further.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var predefined_val = 'test';// your predefined value.
    $.document(ready(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"test/test_script.php", //put relative url here, script which will return php
                data:{}, // if any you would like to post any data
                success:function(response){
                    var data = response; // response data from your php script
                    if(predefined_val !== data){
                        // action you want to perform on value changes.
                    }
                }
            });                     
        },5000);// function will run every 5 seconds
    }));
</script>
```

Comment: I guess that was mentioned later . Now let my answer be here it may useful to others

Comment: Ok :) It was If possible, thats why I didnt focus much on it.